# INSERT INTO WITH SELECT resulting in multiple rows inserted instead of just one

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO `mailinglist_archives`
              (`recipients`) 
               SELECT `email`
               FROM mailinglist
```

**SQL RESULT:**

```
row 1 - xxxx@gmail.com

row 2 - sss@gmail.com

row 3 - abc@gmail.com

row 4 - orange@gmail.com
```

**What i need -**

```
row 1 - xxxx@gmail.com,sss@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com,orange@gmail.com
```

Comment: Looks like you want [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
INSERT INTO `mailinglist_archives`
          (`recipients`) 
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`email`)
           FROM mailinglist
```

That said, this is not a good idea; you should normalize your database, rather than storing lists in columns.

**Edit to address comment:**

You can combine these two queries:

```
$query0 = "INSERT INTO mailinglist_archives (subject, message, datesent) VALUES ('$subject', '$ckcontent', '$timestamp')";
$query01 = "INSERT INTO mailinglist_archives (recipients) SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM mailinglist";
```

like this:

```
INSERT INTO mailinglist_archives (subject, message, datesent, recipients)
SELECT '$subject', '$ckcontent', '$timestamp', GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM mailinglist
```

Again, however, this will result in a (potentially very large) list in the recipients column. This will cause problems, sooner or later, so you are better off normalizing the data by creating a new table to match recipient ids and message ids.

Comment: is there anyway i can consolidate these 2 SQL into ONE?                                $query0 = "INSERT INTO `mailinglist_archives`
              (`subject`, 
              `message`,
               `datesent`) 
              VALUES 
              ('$subject',
              '$ckcontent',
              '$timestamp')";
    
    
    $query01 = "INSERT INTO `mailinglist_archives`
          (`recipients`) 
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`email`)
           FROM mailinglist";

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Appreciated! Well, after a few semesters, i have completely forgotten what is "normalization". I guess time to do research! haha

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO `mailinglist_archives`
              (`recipients`) 
               SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`email`)
               FROM mailinglist
```

Comment: Thank you! Helpful Helpful!:D